# Magento 2 - GitHub credentials on component grid

Tags: magento2, component, web-setup-wizard

I installed a plugin for `Magento 2.1.3` from GitHub ( to be more specific, its the PayPal Plus from iways ) after successfully installing and activating it my `websetup wizard` stops working when i want to update / install extensions from the `Magento Marketplace`.

After a while of loading i get a `500 ( Internal Server Error )`

---

**Error shown in Chrome**

```
GET http://host.domain/setup/index.php/componentGrid/components 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

After previeing the XHR element i see the following:

```
Message:
Command "show" failed: Failed to clone the git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus.git' '/usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/var/composer_home/cache/vcs/git-github.com-i-ways-magento2-paypal-plus.git/'  



show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [package] [version]


Stack trace:
#0 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/ComponentGrid.php(98): Magento\Setup\Model\PackagesData->syncPackagesData()
#1 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\ComponentGrid->componentsAction()
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#5 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

I hope someone can help me with that :)

**Update:**
I tried adding a accesstoken to the auth.json, no errors anymore but infinite loading and not showing the components.

Comment: Have you checked for `auth.json` in your root Magento installation and `var/composer_home/auth.json`?

Comment: Yup, theres no `auth.json` inside the root directory, but one in `var/composer_home/`. After adding a github access token there it just loads and loads and loads, nothing happens anymore, not even the error.

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache` and check logs inside `var/log/`

Comment: Cleared the `var/log` directory and went to the `websetup wizard - components` again. Just some `system.log` and `debug.log` but nothing related to my problem

Comment: Is there an article about "adding GitHub to auth.json" or something similar ? Maybe i got something on that wrong.

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/743

Comment: Thanks, had nothing to do with the `auth.json` so the problem is still existend

Comment: Can you try upgrade from the CLI?

Comment: Yes, i can do everything with the CLI, no problems there. It's just the `Websetup` that wont work. But as i got some people over here who cant work with the CLI the `Websetup` is the easy way

Comment: Upgrading the Magento applications and extensions you obtain from Magento Marketplaces and other sources can require up to 2GB of RAM. If you are using a system with less than 2GB of RAM, we recommend you create a swap file; otherwise, your upgrade might fail.
Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: While still in development and configuration for everything im up to 8GB RAM - once that is over i'll decrease it to 4GB in production mode. So that should not be the problem.

Comment: Have you set those settings in your php.ini : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

I contacted i-ways and let them install the module, everything works fine now. No clue what went wrong as i did it.